# Wordpress Permalink Settings not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed a test blog on [RichBloggers](http://richbloggers.com) Domain. I am trying to use permalinks. With My current settings as follow

[image]

The site links works but with query string in url like

[image]

But when I change the setting to post name

[image]

My Links give me error

[image]

Here is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Actually your path is wrong. Open admin and then view the categories and check the url of the category.

Comment: I am using sample data, all categories, posts were imported by importer

Comment: Please share your site url and admin details let me check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The Hosting Server I am using has old Plesk on it and doesn't have cPanel so the PHP version is outdated. URL rewrite is not working because Mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Answer (score -1):

check by deactivating other plugins once and check by setting theme from WordPress default theme.
and then by setting permalink again.
check if this issue still coming. otherwise it will be conflict issue.

Answer (score -2):

Simple click again the permalinks post name radio button and save it, it will solve your problem now.
Check if the category exist if not then it would throw that error.